# How to have Kile interpret TeX code when file extension is not .tex?

Tags: external-files, kile

To produce my figures, I often use Inkscape with its *export in Pdf+LaTeX* feature. It allows to create a PDF associated with a TeX file which contains the text. Such TeX files have the specific extension `.pdf_tex` instead of `.tex`, which is convenient to make obvious they are linked to a PDF file.

The problem is: Kile does not recognize them as real TeX files and its behavior changes: for example the Comment/Uncomment tool is not available.

Is there a way to tell Kile to recognize a `.pdf_tex` (or any other user defined extension) as it does for a `.tex`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I wouldn't consider `.pdf_tex` as a _convenient_ extension. Why not just `file-pdf.tex` or something like this?

Comment: You can manually set Tools -> Highlighting -> Markup -> LaTeX.

Comment: @yo' : I agree with you, but this is imposed by Inkscape.

Comment: @Astrinus : Thank you, that is what I was looking for. Any suggestion to apply this setting automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually set `Tools -> Highlighting -> Markup -> LaTeX`.

For autorecognition you can try to add the custom extension to the TeX MIME type in your system settings.